# Opening print dialog using java.awt.Desktop

Tags: java, printing, awt

I am trying to print an HTML file using `java.awt.Desktop.print` but the print dialog throws an `IOException`.

```
menuPrint.setOnAction((ActionEvent t) -> {
     if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.PRINT)) {
            try {
                File output = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")+"/Preview.html");
                desktop.print(output);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to print C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\Preview.html. 
    Error message: A device attached to the system is not functioning.
```

I have a PDF printer installed and can open the print dialog using Ctrl+P. Though this same code is working on a separate machine which is connected to an actual printer.

Any clues appreciated.  How to make it work?

Comment: I've never tried printing with Desktop.  I've always used java.awt.print.PrinterJob.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc Do you have any sample code for that?

Comment: [A Basic Printing Program](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html) Oracle tutorial.

Comment: @Sudip Saha: I'm suffering exactly the same problem. Found a solution for it?

Comment: @PieterDegraeuwe unfortunately not. Though i bypassed this by allowing user to take a print out from browser control itself.